# Trying to make a drag to stretch element, why is it so jumpy?

Tags: javascript, resize

I'm trying to create a dragbar so users can stretch the height or width of an element on my page (not interested in using HTML resize).

It seems like I'm pretty close, but I can't figure out why
1) the moveable bar is jumping all over the page
2) the adjustable div is flickering as the size changes (or sometimes disappearing completely).

You can see the demo at http://jsfiddle.net/dYUz7/

Here's the source

```
        var elem = $('.layout');
        var resizeBar = $('.resize-bar',elem),
        adjustableWrapper = $('.layout-container-wrapper',elem),
        posDir = 'Left',
        pos = 'X';


        if($(elem).hasClass('layout-updown')){
            posDir = 'Top';
            pos = 'Y';
        } 

        var startPos = resizeBar[0]['offset'+posDir], i = resizeBar[0]['offset'+posDir];
          resizeBar.on('mousedown', function(event) {
            // Prevent default dragging of selected content
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log(event);
            $(document).on('mousemove', mousemove);
            $(document).on('mouseup', mouseup);
          });

          function mousemove(event) {
            i = event['page'+pos] - startPos;
            if(pos==='X') return changeSizeWidth(i,event.offsetX);
            return changeSizeHeight(i,event.offsetY);
          }

          function changeSizeWidth(i,width){
            resizeBar.css({left : i +'px'});
            adjustableWrapper.css({'width': width +'px'});
            console.log(adjustableWrapper.css('width'));
          }

          function changeSizeHeight(i,height){
            resizeBar.css({top : i +'px'});
            adjustableWrapper.css({'height': height +'px'});
            console.log(adjustableWrapper.css('height'));
          }
          function mouseup() {
            $(document).unbind('mousemove', mousemove);
            $(document).unbind('mouseup', mouseup);
          }
```

Please don't respond with suggestions for using libraries, I have jQuery in the sample, but I'm using angular in the project, and am trying to not add a bunch of other libraries at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting this working by changing the move from the move-bar element to the element which needs to grow or shrink.

The css is a bit messed up, but here's an updated jsfiddle of the result
http://jsfiddle.net/dYUz7/2/

`function changeSizeWidth(left){
                adjustableWrapper.css({'width': left +'px'});
              }`